How to make lualine transparent in LunarVim?
I am new to Neovim so my apologies for such a simple question.
I have tried to make my entire LunarVim config transparent but whatever I try, i am not able to make my lualine transparent.
Most solutions ask me to use
require('lualine').setup({ options = { theme = sometheme })

but when i do this, my LSP tells me function takes a minimum of 0 arguments, 1 provided
My current setup (lualine) :
image
is there any way to fix this ?
any feedback is appreciated
(sorry if this question has been asked already, but none of them solved my question)

Please add your current setup for Lualine as text, not with a attached image (also you attached wrong image).

I have not setup lualine, i am just using the default one from lunarvim, (the image is correct, i have checked from an alt id, the image is for displaying how my current lualine looks not for displaying any setup from a lua file)
